# Is there a term for this interpretation of reality?

Tags: idealism, quantum-interpretations, subjectivity

I am currently digging information in regards to subjective and objective realities and I was wondering if there is a name or a term for the following interpretation of reality.

It goes like this:

> Only subjective reality to be considered real, where the apparent
>   objective reality rules of physics are defined by the only reality
>   compatible with all actors who experience subjective realities.

Please note that I recently moved this question from Physics Stack Exchange.

Comment: To identify this world-view I'd need a better description, as I cannot disentangle this one.The quote appears to endorse 'subjective Idealism'.  A subject requires an object so the idea that only the subjective is real is not common.

Comment: The traditional term is [subjective idealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjective_idealism). For an interesting modern twist on it see [Subjective Interpretation of Quantum Physics by Ruyant](https://www.neuroquantology.com/article.php?id=2288).

Comment: @Conifold, your link to  [subjective idealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjective_idealism) redirected me to [monism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monism) which provide this nice [diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Dualism-vs-Monism.png). From this diagram, I would say that the Monism Idealism would be similar to what I am referring to, I would simply define it as `Matter < Mind(s)` instead of `Matter < Mind`. Thx for your guidance.

Comment: "Monism" is not a specific term, it refers to any philosophy with a single "root nature" of reality. In particular, materialism and idealism are both monisms, and there is nothing it says concerning subjective/objective.